# Is Dijkstras algorithm used in modern route-finding systems?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path, applied-theory

Is Dijkstra's algorithm used in modern route-finding systems such as Google maps or the satnav in your car? If not, then what is?

Comment: I guess you mean the routing component that finds your way, once the GPS, which is primarily a Global **Positionning** Syatem has determined **where you are**. Yet another case of a tail wagging a dog.

Comment: I can't give a source for this, but my current Algorithms lecturer works in industry, and says that $A^*$ is used a lot in practice, especially for GPS. If you use Euclidean Distance as a heuristic, you tend to get improvements over Dijstra's by ignoring paths that are nonsensical in real life. You might already know, but Dijkstra's can be described as $A^*$ with heuristic $h(x) = 0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Dijkstra's algorithm is used in modern maps systems. A lengthy and informative discussion can be found in the following question from StackOverflow: 
[What algorithms compute directions from point A to point B on a map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430142/what-algorithms-compute-directions-from-point-a-to-point-b-on-a-map)

Answer (score 8):

Google Maps in 2009 used [Contraction Hierarchies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_hierarchies) - see [this tech talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-0ErpE8tQbw).

Since then, some mind-blowing methods have been discovered, capable of doing cross-country routing in fractional milliseconds - the so-called "two-hop labeling distance oracles". See [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fjirSXt56OI), or search for "Hub labeling" or "Shortest paths for the masses". I think I heard Bing uses this one. It also has applications like the ability to find the nearest point of interest (e.g. nearest gas station) with a complexity independent on the number of gas stations.

Comment: This seem to be useful references. However, can you a) give citable references and/or b) paint the broad picture of how these work? In particular, do they solve the problem exactly?